# Windows 10: bluetooth headphones work as a Handsfree but unable to connect to Stereo

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, a2dp

Here are some more details. My laptop is ASUS ROG GL502VS. I tried this with Jabra Elite 65t and Jabra Stealth, both of which support A2DP. The pairing goes smoothly and everything seems to be installed correctly.

[image: Bluetooth devices] [image: Audio devices] [image: Devices and printers] [image: Headset services]

Note that the stereo device is present as well as the Audio Sink service in the headset. However the Headphone audio output is "disconnected".

[image]

Right-clicking on the Headphones entry and choosing "Connect" does absolutely nothing. No error messages, no reaction at all. The entry stays disconnected. Disconnecting the Handsfree first does not help. Unticking the Handsfree Telephony service in the device properties does not help. Rebooting, re-pairing, installing the latest driver, clean reinstall of the driver via safe mode does not help.

### A bit of history

This worked fine a few days ago. Then at some point I turned on my headphones and got a Blue Screen of Death. I blame some automatic update because I didn't update anything myself. I only uninstalled Razer Synapse before that happened, which might or might not be a coincidence. I couldn't connect to Bluetooth Stereo after that.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Fixed it by unticking "Remotely controlled device" along with "Hands-free Telephony". Both are found in the same place.

Comment: in this case headset works just as speakers and I don't have micro at the sound settings of windows, only default audio jack

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. 
Here is what worked for me: Go to Run, type devmgmt.msc, expand the Bluetooth menu and uninstalled both the headset and stereo device of your headset. Then go to Bluetooth setting and remove them from the paired devices. Once I paired again, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that I had a video call app open that had access to my microphone. When your microphone is active, only handsfree audio is available - stereo audio is disabled. When I closed the video call app I was once again able to use stereo.

Answer (score 0):

I found on the web best solution. Go to RUN->Control Panel->Devisec and printers->right button on a bluetooth headphones->properties-> Equipment-> Choose driver like on a screen and change it on a Transport Driver.

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: It is best to embed images directly rather than links to hosting sites.

Comment: It's also best to provide screenshots that are in English